# How do I update code to show random walk?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on plotting a random walk using MATPLOTLIB. What is the codew below missing?

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk():
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

def fill_walk(self):
    while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
        x_direction = choice([1, -1])
        x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
        x_step = x_direction * x_distance

        y_direction = choice([1, -1])
        y_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
        y_step = y_direction * y_distance

        if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
            continue

        next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
        next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

        self.x_values.append(next_x)
        self.y_values.append(next_y)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import RandomWalk

rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()
plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)
plt.show()
```

The error I get is as follows: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'random_walk'"

Comment: Well, what is module `random_walk`?  Class `RandomWalk` is defined locally, but you're trying to `import` it.

Comment: Is your problem solved by the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have saved the class in a file called `random_walk.py` located in the same directory as the file with rest of your code to plot an create the class instance, you just need to get rid of the `from random_walk import RandomWalk` and fix the indentation of your class' method called `fill_walk(self)`

```
from random import choice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class RandomWalk():
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):
        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
            x_direction = choice([1, -1])
            x_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance

            y_direction = choice([1, -1])
            y_distance = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue

            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)


rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()
plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)
plt.show()
```

[image]